# carrier weathermaker 8000 not working properly

Tags: hvac

carrier weathermaker8000  when you request heat  the blower motor comes on no inducer motor  which should be first to come on blower runs for 3 to 5 minutes then turns off then inducer motor comes on then ignitor valve opens has heat for a few minutes then gas valve  shut off getting  error codes 13 & 31 goes back & forth
FYI the furnace was working correct when removed  when reinstalled at another location (not the same house) when the problems arose owner installed his self 27v @ circuit board I think it has restriction in exhaust but why would blower motor come on first instead of inducer motor?

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]! Please [edit] this to add some punctuation, capitalization, and formatting. The easier it is to read, the easier it will be to answer...